# What can be wrong when Web API stopped working in all my jquery calls?

Tags: jquery, webapi

I have a website using html,css and jquery. I use jquery to send and retrieve data from a sql database. Many of my calls have worked perfectly, but suddently not any works anymore. I have not ant clue whats going on right  now. The only thing what did happen was that jquery stopped working and I had to pull: 
 into my code again. Where to look for solving this errror?

`````
 @ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login_page4.aspx.cs" Inherits="apiwebsite.Login_page4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title>Login_page4</title>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.0.slim.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.0.intellisense.js"></script>
<script>
        function clock()
        {
            document.getElementById("displayTime").innerHTML = Date();
        }           

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            setInterval(clock, 1000);
            document.getElementById("selectmachine").style.height = "30px";
            document.getElementById("selectmachine").style.backgroundColor = "#f2f2f2";
            $("#selectmachine").css("width", "200px");


            document.getElementById("selectoperator").style.height = "30px";
            document.getElementById("selectoperator").style.backgroundColor = "#f2f2f2";
            $("#selectoperator").css("width", "200px");

            document.getElementById("notice").style.color = "red";


            $("#butlogin").css("width", "200px");
            $("#butlogin").css('backgroundColor', '#f2f2f2');

            $("#butlogout").css("width", "200px");
            $("#butlogout").css('backgroundColor', '#f2f2f2');

            $("#order").css("width", "200px");
            $("#order").css('backgroundColor', '#f2f2f2');

            $("#material").css("width", "200px");
            $("#material").css('backgroundColor', '#f2f2f2');


            logonmachine();
            GetSelected(callback);

});
        function logonmachine() {


            $("#butlogin").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                selected = 1;

                alert('Selected er: ' + selected)

                if (selected == 1) {

                    $("#notice").html("Du er nu logget ind..")
                    T = login();
                    alert(T);
logout(T);

                }

                else {
                    $("#notice").html("Du er allerede logget ind..")
                }
            });


 function login() {

         var d = new Date();   //insert data in table login
         var time = d.getTime();
         return time;

     };


     function logout(T) {
         var date = new Date();
         var logout = date.getTime();
         var insert = {};
         insert.login_time2 = T;
         insert.logout_time2 = logout;
         insert.name = $("#selectoperator").val();
         insert.ordernumber = $("#order").val();
         insert.material = $("#material").val();
         insert.machinename = $("#selectmachine").val();

         $("#Butlogin").show();

         $.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost:52059/api/logout/login",
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "Application/json;charset=utf-8",
             data: JSON.stringify(insert),
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (response) {
                 alert(response)
             }
         });
     };



     ````
`````

Comment: Without code examples, error examples, and more details, we cannot help you solve this problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: All of my calls to my database is not working, but what code do you need to see?

Comment: If you're having trouble with calls to databases, the code relating to the database calls would be relevant in this situation. Please also let us know the exact errors you're receiving.

Comment: My controller works fine. I'll test it in Postman

Comment: Does the function `logout()` make a call to an API that calls the database? And is that where it's failing? If not, where is it failing?

Comment: Yes. I have removed all code except function login(), logout and logonmachine. Logout function should "post" data to my database. Its has been working before. But now none off my "GET" or "POST"  works anymore

Comment: What happens when you GET or POST? errors? Perhaps in the `$.ajax` call you can add an entry for `error: function(err) { console.log(err)}` and see if that gives you more details.

Comment: I added:  error:function(error)
             {
                 console.log(error)
             }, But no error came...

Comment: The logout function should POST data into my Login table. But no data is inserted into the table. All the code has been working before.

Comment: Error fund: I some how changed Jquery to the slim version 3.4.1.slim.js. This does not work.  It must be full version. Thanks for help any way